# Alternative for boxplot with log-x scale

Tags: data-visualization, logarithm, boxplot

I am analyzing the behavior of a distribution with a logarithmic x-scale on a pretty large range. Initially, I thought using boxplots might be a good idea to understand how the data behaved, but now I am trying to present the information in a more accessible way and for my data boxplot becomes unreadable. Here is an example on a reduced x-range:

[image: boxplot with logged x scale]

What is a good alternative to represent this particular type of data? My idea so far is making an area plot where the means follow a line, the stds follow one color and the quartiles a different color. Something similar to this:

[image]

Is there a tool that does that? Preferable for matlab or python.

Comment: John Tukey (inventor of the boxplot) called this a [wandering schematic plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=wandering%20schematic).